# How may I filter results with a regexp_like (...'[^\_...]$)?

Tags: regex, oracle10g

Aloha

I need to filter results. I did with 'not like' constraint. But I'd like to be more effiscient.

Here is what I've tried :
in a 'not like' style

`

```
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_S')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_T')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_X')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_Y')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_L')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_SG')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_ST')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_X1')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_Y1')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_X2')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_Y2')
  AND S.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE ('%_O')`
```

and in a regex :

```
  REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME, '[^\_O|Y]*')
```

The regexp_like clause doesnt' work as I expect. But I don't see how to write it. I want all results except those ending with _O, _Y, _X,...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with oracle flavour of regex, but after having a brief look at their docs, I would expect something like this to work:

```
.*?_(O|Y|Z)$
```

or

```
.*?_[OYZ]$
```

It says:

- `.*?` - match anything followed by (non greedy match)
- `_` - underscore literal, followed by
- `(O|Y|Z)` - O or Y or Z (this is a capturing group - in standard regex I would use (?:) instead but it might not be supported
- `$` - at the end of the string

The alternative is with a character class `[OYZ]` which means any of these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
NOT REGEXP_LIKE (COLUMN_NAME, '_([STXYLO]|S[GT]|[XY][12])$')
```

Comment: @Brindavoine, welcome to SO! You should [accept answers that answer you question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/163680) and feel free to vote answers up if they helped you. :-)